# How to find the maximum of a function given by a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, math, user-input

I need to extract the maximum of a mathematical expression written in the Python notation (like `-2*(x+1)**2`) and the point at which it occurs given by a string (that should be introduced by the user).

I could do it using eval or exec but I'm trying to find alternatives to that.

I've tried to use scypy to compute the maximum with the following code:

```
def f(x):   
    return -2*(x+1)**2
exec(cont)
max_x = scipy.optimize.fmin(lambda x: -f(x), 0, disp=False)
print(max_x)
```

But I can't figure out how to extract the function on the string and put it on the first line without using exec.

Comment: You should check out the AST module in python. Especially `ast.literal_eval` could be of use for you

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

Comment: Why exactly are you looking for alternatives? What should they do/not do?

Comment: What is `cont`?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you are looking for? Do you want to create a function without using ``exec``/``eval``? Do you just want to find the minimum of a formula in a string?

Comment: @Nathan I'm looking for exec and eval alternatives because I've read in other answers that they are not safe (In this case, user could input malicious code and eval/exec would run it).

Comment: @RubenGameiro what exactly are you intending to use this for? It might be worth just writing your own parser https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-write-a-formula-string-parser-in-python-5362210afeab

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I just want to find the maximum of a formula on a string and the point at which it occurs.

Comment: Note that the problem of ``eval``/``exec`` is that it runs arbitrary code. However, minimizing a function numerically necessarily means *running* it, so you will end up running that arbitrary code anyways.

Comment: @RubenGameiro Wait. The comment to Nathan says the goal is to find an alternative to exec/eval. The comment to me says the goal is to maximise the formula. Which is it?

Comment: @Nathan  I'm planning to use this for a project where user inputs the function and then with the maximum value of the function and other user inputs I want to compute certain values to display at the end, but I will take a look at your link.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sorry for the confusion. The goal is to find the maximum of a function on a string without using eval or exec. So, all possible solutions will end up using some form of eval?

Comment: @RubenGameiro if they're executing it on their own computer, it doesn't really matter if there are security issues (what are they going to do, hack their own pc?)

Answer (score 1):

**I just read you already found `eval` and `exec` so this won't be of much help. I'll leave the answer up for others just in case.**

You can use the `eval` function like this to optimize:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize


class OptimizeFunction:

    def __init__(self, formula):
        self.formula = formula

    def evaluate(self, x):
        return eval(self.formula)

    def eval_mirrored(self, x):
        return -self.evaluate(x)

    def get_max(self):
        # Use the mirrored function to get the maximum value
        print(minimize(fun=self.eval_mirrored, x0=[0]))


string = '-2*(x+1)**2'
optimize_function = OptimizeFunction(formula=string)
optimize_function.get_max()
```

Results in:

```
      fun: 1.1101586378198223e-16
 hess_inv: array([[0.25]])
      jac: array([8.64197602e-13])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 9
      nit: 2
     njev: 3
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([-1.00000001])
```